# How to use days of week as right axis labels with MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

When I'm using the code below only the first value gets changed to "Mo", but the rest of the values are the same. How can I edit my code to make it work?

```
mChart.getAxisRight().setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter());
```

```
class MyValueFormatter : ValueFormatter() {
    private val days = arrayOf("Mo", "Tu", "Wed", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su")

    override fun getAxisLabel(value: Float, axis: AxisBase?): String {
        return days.getOrNull(value.toInt()) ?: value.toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use XAxis() instead of AxisRight(). it can be more useful for you. Because left/right axis is for values not texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is your values are not matching the days array indexes. First one is matching with 0 index hence it is showing but other values are 20, 40, 60 ... that are OutOfArrayIndexBounds. So to solve this problem you have to create a map instead of array. Here I solved your problem:

```
    class MyValueFormatter : ValueFormatter() {
        private val days = mapOf(0.0f to "Mon", 20.0f to "Tu", 40.0f to "Wed", 60.0f to "Th", 80.0f to "Fr", 100.0f to "Sa", 120.0f to "Su")

        override fun getAxisLabel(value: Float, axis: AxisBase?): String {
            return if (days.containsKey(value)) days[value] else value.toString()
        }
    }
```